# Java/Grails library for Twitter: JTwitter, Twitter4J or Grails plugin?

Tags: java, grails, twitter

I'm looking to integrate a new app (to be built, probably in Grails) with Twitter and found there are (at least) 3 libraries to use. [JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php), [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org) and a [Grails plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/twitter).

Any opinions on the pros and cons of each are appreciated.

I'll mark this as a community wiki as there's no single answer expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grails plugin uses JTwitter. To me Twitter4j looks better, because:

- it *looks* more serious - they provide the git repository, javadoc, support matrix. JTwitter don't.
- At the bottom of the JTwitter page it says that you must include a backlink if you use it.

Answer (score 4):

As the main developer of JTwitter I'm somewhat biased, but here's my 2 cents:

- There's not much in it either way.
- Twitter4j does have a nicer looking website (but their code examples use basic auth and are out of date).
- Twitter4J currently covers a bit more of the Twitter API, namely streaming.
- JTwitter is cleaner and simpler - it uses a lot less classes to do the same thing.
- JTwitter has better exception handling and some robustness features for when Twitter is flaky.

Comment: NB - You are asked to add a backlink when using JTwitter, as a very small token of thanks. But if you resent giving credit, then you don't legally have to add a backlink.