# what to use twitter4j or jtwitter

Tags: android, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best java twitter library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851767/best-java-twitter-library)

hello there i need to create full fledged twitter application(everything) for android then which way do u suggest.which api should i use i came to know about jtwitter and twitter4j which one is better?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691990/java-grails-library-for-twitter-jtwitter-twitter4j-or-grails-plugin

Comment: btw remember that Twitter has called developers to stop developing twitter application. So think of developing for something else :)

Comment: @Mayu official statement link plz

Comment: I want to directly interact with twitter servers without using browser

Comment: has anybody used this? http://www.androidlibs.com/sociallib.html